# User input without delaying program

Tags: python-3.x, server, console

I am making a server program that lists the client messages, but, I need to implement a server 'console' that can print and use user input as commands
. But, the input() builtin for python will not let print() output data to py console.

```
## code example
import time

while true:
    print('Working')
    time.sleep(0.1) # so doesn't crash
    var = input('Delays prog')
```

but my problem, is that the input() function interrupts threads and normal printing of data on the python console

like so:

```
============= RESTART: /home/pi/Desktop/Pythonic/Chat/Server.py =============
Server name : serv
Server running on localhost at port 5386
> Connected To
 ('127.0.0.1', 43686)
00:58:31 : [Guest]Owner: Hello
```

the offending piece of code:

```
host = 'localhost'
port = random.randint(5000,6000)
user = 'No one'

name = input('Server name : ')

server = Server(host, port, user)

clients = {}
threads = []

while True:
    client, caddr = server.socket.accept()
    # name extraction
    name = client.recv(1024)
    #name = getname(caddr)

    clients[client] = name.decode('utf-8')

    thread = threading.Thread(target=recv_loop, args=(server,client, caddr))
    thread.start()
    action = input('> ')
```

Comment: Are you using sockets to communicate? If not, then you need to learn about `sockets`. You can start here : https://realpython.com/python-sockets/ .

If you are using sockets, then you can easily get user input the `.accept() and .recv(..)` methods.

Comment: you didn't show `recv_loop` code and what is _really_ the issue. It crashes? incorrect output? which one is it? thanks

Comment: what i need is the server program to be able to print the client data and be able to run 'commands' at the same time, so, if a user sends a message while i am typing a command, it prints the message before the command

Comment: you have only one console. So if program prints stuff while you're typing, well, that's expected. How do you want it to behave?

Comment: I want it to keep printing client input while serv console